# Error on showing Integer in TextView?

Tags: android

Hi I would like to ask why am I having an error when I try to show an Integer in the Textview Here is my Code on the btnClear it works fine but on Confirm it shows some error only When I have the "tvCoin.setText("Coin");" code. thanks for the help in advance

```
            case R.id.btnConfirm:
                if (Answer.equals(correctAnswer))
                {
                    tvCategory.setText("Correct");
                    Coin = Coin + 3;
                    tvCoin.setText("Coin");
                }
                else
                {
                    tvCategory.setText("Wrong");
                }
            break;
            case R.id.btnClear:
                Answer = "";
                tvAns.setText(Answer);
            break;
```

Comment: What is the error? And is `tvCoin` initialized properly?

Comment: is `Coin` an int value and do you have  `tvCoin.setText(Coin)` and not  `tvCoin.setText("Coin");`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an integer you have to turn it into string before printing on the screen:

```
someinteger.toString();
```

Comment: what do you mean by printing on the screen

Comment: I think the confusion is with the title. It says "Integer" but those are clearly `String`s in the `setText()` methods

Comment: Yes it is confusing, but if the title is correct this is what he should do. Otherwise meh..

Comment: @codeMagic i guess its `tvCoin.setText(Coin);` Coin being integer.

Comment: @Esq in that case op should use `String.valueOf(Coin)`

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, I agree. I think the OP wants to use `Coin` and for some reason has `"Coin"`. So most likely they want `tvCoin.setText("" + Coin);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
    int Coin;
    tvCoin.setText(Coin);
```

B'coz if you will try to setText as Integer it will throw Exception `Resources.NotFoundException`

So You should use like

```
tvCoin.setText(String.valueOf(Coin));
```

Comment: What do I keep missing? Nowhere do I see `tvCoin.setText(Coin);`. I do agree that I think that is what the OP is after

Comment: @codeMagic i agree and only thing that i guess upon is    `Coin = Coin + 3` relating to the title. But would be guess.

Comment: @codeMagic yes i agree.. This may be only reason we are assuming.

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing wrong with this code

```
tvCategory.setText("Correct");
Coin = Coin + 3;
tvCoin.setText("Coin");
```

But might be you wanna try to print "Coin"
[First See rule of Textview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

So your code look like this :-

```
tvCoin.setText(""+Coin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here here you are doing wrong `tvCoin.setText("Coin");` if you will do this it will print coin
and if you will do this `tvCoin.setText(Coin);` also wrong it will give you an exception like `ResourceNotFound` because `Coin` is not a `resource id` its int variable.you can't pass integer into `setText()` method .the correct way is `tvCoin.setText(String.valueOf(Coin));` you can only pass the `String values of integer`.